# Using the Visual Studio Express 2010 Environment

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

I just began Using the Visual Studio Express 2010 Environment, and I am missing some of the things I came to know and love when programming in Java using Netbeans. Some features I'd like to know how to use/if visual studio has are:

"Shopping for Options": In Netbeans, when I type "Sting." a pop down menue appears and lets me know all the options I have that I can put next. Is there any way to get this in studio?

Error Highlighting: Net beans can underline stuff in red when the syntax is wrong, and to some extent explain why. Is there any way to get this in studio?

Auto formatting: Netbeans can fix all the indenting and stuff with a quick click, can visual studio do this?

Answers to any of these questions are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Java has a somewhat cleaner syntax, which means its error-reporting capability is a bit better. The red underlines will be less accurate, as a result: you might get an error when you use `X` instead at the earlier definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I normally press:

```
 ctrl + space
```

for auto completion, or after writing . you will also get auto complete combobox

Error Highlighting:

My VSC++ 2010 Express does underline with red any possible error

Auto formatting:

Edit -> Format Selection

Comment: ..but payed versions of Visual Studio do underline obvious errors in code.